# How to get access to audio stream in my webcam microphone using av.open()?

Tags: python-3.x, audio-streaming, microphone, webcam-capture

I use [av](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV) python library in my project. If we use `av.open("video.mp4")` for mp4 file we get an audio stream and video stream. When i try getting both streams from my webcam using `av.open("/dev/video0")` it returns only video stream. My question is how can i get a webcam audio stream using av library?
Should i search answer in format or in microphone hardware address?
thx)

Comment: Hey, Webcam doesn't have any microphone ! So you should select different device that stream audio from device list.

Answer (score 1):

if someone need. `av.open("default", format="pulse")` See more: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse